# Babel will not transpile Javascript default value parameters for IE11

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, core-js

**My javascript file**

```
require('core-js');

const dzsHelpers = require('./js_common/_dzs_helpers');
const dzsapHelpers = require('./jsinc/_dzsap_helpers'); <-- THE CODE IS HERE
const dzsapComments = require('./jsinc/components/_comments'); [ ... ]
```

**My webpack**

```
{
        test: middleExtensionRegex,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          sourceMaps: true,
          minified: true,
          sourceType: "unambiguous",
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', {
              useBuiltIns: 'entry',
              corejs: {version: 3},
              debug: true,
              forceAllTransforms: true,
              loose: true,
              "forceAllTransforms": true,
              "targets": {
                "chrome": "58",
                "ie": "11"
              }
            }]
          ],
          "plugins": [
            ["@babel/plugin-transform-parameters", {}],
            ["@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"],
            [
              "@babel/transform-runtime",
              {
                "regenerator": true
              },
            ]
          ],
          ignore: ['node_modules']
        },
        // options for the loader
      }
```

this does what I need - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-parameters - on paper...
however, the output is always like this
`function(elThis,defaultOptions,argOptions=null,searchedAttr="data-options"){var finalOptio [...]`

and IE11 naturally complains...

Anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you have `"forceAllTransforms": true` listed twice?

Comment: does not really matter

Comment: all tries were futile, the only fix was using closure compiler

Answer (score 0):

All of the tries with babel preset env target browsers ie11 were in vain.

Only solution that worked for me was using Closure Compiler ( webpack 5 ) :

```
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new ClosurePlugin({mode: 'STANDARD'}, {
        debug: true,
        languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
        renaming: false
      })
    ]
  },
```